# How to extract metadata as key value pair using lxml python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I have to scrape meta data as **key-value** pair from web site.
[image: inspect HTML image]

```
meta_name = tree.xpath("//meta[@name]/@content")
```

This will give me value(eg: John Doe) for meta_name but doesn't specify the key(eg:author).

ps: I mentioned example from the uploaded picture

Comment: Thank you. I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
meta_name = tree.xpath("//meta[@name]")  
for elem in meta_name:
    print(elem.attrib)
```

elem.attrib will give us the dict of attributes.